# Update file using fscanf and fprintf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have tab seperated record like this in .txt file

```
1000    Aashir  0213-4211685    123456  0
1001    Muhammad Ali    0334-3387918    abcd    0
1002    Azam    0323-2143133    hassan123   0
1003    Taha Hashmi 0214-6589421    786 0
1004    Khan    03452145698 helloworld  0
```

now i want to update or modify these values using fscanf and fprintf

This is what I've tried so far but now i got stuck on how to write on a specific position

```
void update_record(Account* user)
{
FILE *record;int i=0;
record=fopen("database.txt","a+");
char buffer[SIZE];Account req;
while(fgets(buffer,SIZE,record))
{
    sscanf(buffer,"%d\t%[^\t]\t%s\t%s\t%ld\n",&req.acc_num,req.name,req.mobileno,req.pass,&req.acc_bal);
    ++i;
    if(req.acc_num==user->acc_num){
        fseek(record,SIZE*i-1,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(record,"%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%ld\n",user->acc_num,user->name,user->mobileno,user->pass,user->acc_bal);

        cout<<"\nFIle updated ";
        fclose(record);
        break;

    }
}

return;


}
```

I am beginner please help, i have to use fscanf and fprintf only, #assignmentcriteria :(

Comment: you have to do fseek to go to particular location

Comment: another question Do fscanf changes file pointer to next line ?

Comment: The problem is that you can't really read from and write to the same file simultaneously, not when it's a text file with no fixed-size records. The usual solution is either to read one line at a time from the file, modify the lines you want to modify, and write the lines to a temporary file, then rename the temporary file as the actual file.

Comment: i have updated the code using fseek but it's not working please help ?

Comment: Drop `fseek()`.  On update, 1) create new file with the updated records.  2) delete old original file 3) rename new file to old name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed record size

You can use `fseek` to move to Nth record. You should use `fgets` and `fputs` for all reads and writes and `sscanf` and `snprintf` for formating data in buffer.

With fixed size records, it is very easy to calculate the position of Nth record in the file. You can update one record in place. You can use binary search to find record by id, if your id's are sorted, etc.

Updating record is easy, just use sequential read without `fseek` to locate correct record and replace it with new one. On records sorted by id, you can use binary search to locate correct record and move in file by `fseek`. Then replace data in place.

If you can use position in the file as record ID, it is just one step to locate correct record. It is just one `fseek` to ID*SIZE and modify data in place.

### Variable record size

This is your current situation. Every record is terminated by `\n` character and every item is separated by `\t` character. In this situation `fseek` is not your friend.

To access any record in the file, you must read whole file, line by line using `fscanf`.

To modify one record, you should open temporary file and copy all records before the one you need to modify. Then write modified record using `fprintf`. And then copy all subsequent records till the end of the original file. After that, delete original file and rename temporary file to original name.

Imagine how slow will be every read and update operation.

Comment: I edit my code using fseek but it's not working can u please figure out the mistake ?

Comment: Problem is file format, if you can't change it to fixed record size, just forget `fseek`. Your update function should work just for file, where every line is exactly `SIZE` bytes length.

Comment: I have just updated the answer, so it is now more clear.